# ZF2 navigation. How to show a page in breadcrumbs, but hide this page in menu?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have page for product editing (product/edit/[:id]). I want to show this page in breadcrumbs, but I don't want it to show in navigation menu.

Here is my code in view:

```
echo $this->navigation('admin_navigation')->breadcrumbs(); // for breadcrumbs 
echo $this->navigation('admin_navigation')->menu(); // for menu
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution may not exactly be what you are looking for, but it works.

If you are using some partial template file for the menus or breadcrumbs then you can do the following -

While configuring the navigation in the `module.config.php`, add a custom attribute. 
Eg: `show_in_menu`.

```
array(
    'label' => 'Product List',
    'route' => 'product',
    'action' => 'edit',
    'show_in_menu' => false,
),
```

Then in the partial file check -

```
foreach ($this->container as $page) {
    if($page->get('show_in_menu') !== false) {
        //display the menu
    }
}
```

This way, only the required menus will be displayed.

I hope it helps.

Comment: simple and ingenious

Answer (score 1):

Set the "visible" flag in your "navigation" configuration:

```
[
    'label'      => 'Edit',
    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
    'action'     => 'edit',
    'visible'    => false, // Hidden from menu but will be shown in breadcrumb
],
```

Change

```
echo this->navigation('admin_navigation')->breadcrumbs()
```

to:

```
echo $his->navigation('admin_navigation')->breadcrumbs()->setRenderInvisible(true)
```